# React Native: How do I navigate to a separate screen using a button's onPress?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have an app that has a navigator containing 4 screens, these are displayed using icons in a nav bar at the bottom of my screen:

[image]

and this is how it's setup in my App.js file

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from "@expo/vector-icons";

import WardrobeScreen from "./WardrobeScreen";
import OutfitScreen from "./OutfitScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./ProfileScreen";
import Carousel from "./Carousel";
import UploadMenu from "./UploadMenu";
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} style={{paddingTop: 30}}>
                <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
                               tabBarOptions={{
                                   activeTintColor: 'grey',
                                   inactiveTintColor: '#D3D3D3',
                                   showLabel: false,
                                   style: {
                                       height: 100
                                   }
                               }}>

                    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Carousel} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={33} />
                        ),
                    }} />

                    <Tab.Screen name="Wardrobe" component={WardrobeScreen} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="wardrobe" color={color} size={33} />
                        ),
                    }} />

                    <Tab.Screen name="Outfits" component={OutfitScreen} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="tshirt-crew" color={color} size={33} />
                        ),
                    }}  />

                    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={33} />
                        ),
                    }}  />

                </Tab.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}
```

The + button on the screenshot above should take me to another screen, one that is not a part of the navbar and I do not want it to be displayed on the navbar. It is effectively a sub page of the one shown above.

How can I achieve this functionality?

This is the code for the screen from the screenshot, the FloatingButton component has a pressButton prop which is the onPress. Currently it is `pressButton={() => RootNavigation.navigate('UploadMenu')}` (UploadMenu is the screen I want it to navigate to).

```
import { View, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import FloatingButton from "./FloatingButton";
import TitleBar from "./TitleBar";
import WardrobeItems from "./WardrobeItems";
import * as RootNavigation from './RootNavigation.js';

const WardrobeView = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: '#FF6868'}}>
            <TitleBar pageName='Wardrobe'
                      heading='Your Wardrobe'
                      subHeading='So much to choose from, and space for even more!'
                      backgroundColour='#FF6868'
            />

            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <WardrobeItems />
                <FloatingButton buttonColour='#FF6868'
                                pressButton={() => RootNavigation.navigate('UploadMenu')}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default WardrobeView;
```

I have not been able to find an answer in other similar questions.

EDIT WITH NESTED NAVIGATION: I have tried to use nested navigation to achieve what I want and although I believe it should work it isn't...

WardrobeScreen

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

import TitleBar from "./TitleBar";
import FloatingButton from "./FloatingButton";
import UploadMenu from "./UploadMenu";
import Hello from "./Hello";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const WardrobeScreen = ({ navigation }) => (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: '#FF6868'}}>

        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="UploadMenu" component={UploadMenu} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Hello" component={Hello} />
        </Tab.Navigator>

        <TitleBar pageName='Wardrobe'
                  heading='Your Wardrobe'
                  subHeading='So much to choose from, and space for even more!'
                  backgroundColour='#FF6868'
        />

        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            <Text>Your wardrobe items will go here and scroll down depending on how many you have. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</Text>
            <FloatingButton buttonColour='#FF6868'
                            pressButton={() => navigation.navigate('WardrobeScreen', { screen: 'UploadMenu' })}
            />
        </View>

    </SafeAreaView>
);

export default WardrobeScreen;
```

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from "@expo/vector-icons";

import WardrobeScreen from "./WardrobeScreen";
import OutfitScreen from "./OutfitScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./ProfileScreen";
import Carousel from "./Carousel";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <NavigationContainer style={{paddingTop: 30}}>
                <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
                               tabBarOptions={{
                                   activeTintColor: 'grey',
                                   inactiveTintColor: '#D3D3D3',
                                   showLabel: false,
                                   style: {
                                       height: 100
                                   }
                               }}>

                    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Carousel} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={33} />
                        ),
                    }} />

                    <Tab.Screen name="WardrobeScreen" component={WardrobeScreen} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="wardrobe" color={color} size={33} />
                        ),
                    }} />

                    <Tab.Screen name="Outfits" component={OutfitScreen} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="tshirt-crew" color={color} size={33} />
                        ),
                    }}  />

                    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={33} />
                        ),
                    }}  />

                </Tab.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Read the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/

Comment: The docs don't help me I'm afraid, nothing I could find about my specific issue.

Comment: If you read the docs it talks about something called as nesting navigation, in your case you need to nest stack navigation inside one of your bottom bar tab

Comment: That gives me a navigation menu at the top of that screen, which I don't want... I just need that one button to take me to this extra screen

Comment: You need to configure the stack to not have a topbar by adding headerShown false in options or screenOptions

Comment: I have edited my question, the button still does not work with this nested navigation... perhaps I have it setup wrong?

Comment: It would be nice if you add a https://snack.expo.io/ demo, it will be easier to debug the issue.

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@ollie_saunderson/intelligent-french-fries

Comment: To be run on ios btw, there is an issue regarding snap-carousel which doesn't allow web to work...